# No module named 'nltk.lm' in Google colaboratory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, nltk, nltk-trainer

I'm trying to import the NLTK language modeling module  ([nltk.lm](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.lm.html)) in a Google colaboratory notebook without success. I've tried by installing everything from nltk, still without success.

What mistake or omission could I be making?

Thanks in advance.

[image].
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Colab has `nltk v3.2.5` installed, but `nltk.lm` (Language Modeling package) [was added in `v3.4`](https://www.nltk.org/news.html#id4).

In your Google Colab run:

```
!pip install -U nltk
```

In the output you will see it downloads a new version, and uninstalls the old one:

```
...
Downloading nltk-3.6.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
...
Successfully uninstalled nltk-3.2.5
...
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
```

Click the `Restart runtime` button shown in the end of the output.

Now it should work!

You can double check the `nltk` version using this code:

```
import nltk
print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.__version__))
```

You need `v3.4` or later to use `nltk.lm`.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your sharing your knowledge and valuable time.